# Convert Access 2007 date/time to text, mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: datetime, text, ms-access-2007

I need to convert a Date/Time in Access (it comes from an Oracle database but Access is the only tool I'm allowed to use to access it) to plain text.

I have found lots of web pages that talk about how to convert from text to date, but I have not found any that can convert date to text without having to code a VBA function. I would like to find an Access 2007 way to do this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(PURGE_DATE ,'mm/dd/yyyy'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM PATRON;
```

How can I do this?  I've been beating my head against this for three hours now.

I did some more searching and found that this works for part of my need:

```
SELECT format(PURGE_DATE ,'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM PATRON;
```

That flips the fields around, but it does not convert it to text.

Comment: "I have not found any [method] that can convert date to text without having to code a VBA function"  - I seriously doubt that. This is so common a need.

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
SELECT Format([PURGE_DATE],"yyyy-mm-dd") FROM PATRON;
```

*will* convert `PURGE_DATE` to text as *Format* always returns text.

But - referring to your Oracle query - perhaps `PURGE_DATE` is text and not date.

If so:

```
SELECT Format(CDate([PURGE_DATE]), "yyyy-mm-dd") FROM PATRON;
```